# Preferred way of letting BLoCs collaborate

Tags: flutter, reactive-programming

I'm build an application in flutter using blocs. A one point I have a FAB button where I can navigate to a page where I can add data. This page consists of a root, the page A itself which includes a tabbar with 3 tabs B, C and D.

What I want to do is create an instance of a "person" and save it from Page A as this page has an overall save button. On each of the tabs B, C and D I can change details about the person I'm saving. So far I've created a bloc for each of the pages. 
Now my question is how I make this collaboration simple and clean to ensure when I click Save on Page A I have all the data changed/collected in each tab.
Should I:

1. Make the root page A Create the object of a person and pass it to
   each sub bloc as a reference.
2. Let the root page A listen for streams
   of each sub bloc
3. Something else :) ?

Just to be clear, I expect the Root page A to do all the saving using a service/repository..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the tabs are doing is editing the same person object, use ONE PersonBloc for all views. If the tabs need there own Blocs for other business logic they can pipe the changes to the PersonBloc.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. Writing the question made me think in that direction too :) Thanks!